# Getting the part of string from the URL using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have the following URL in the browser address bar

```
http://localhost:8080/MyApp/MyScreen?userName=ccc
```

I need to get the part `/MyScreen?userName=ccc` from the it, excluding the root.

How can i get this using jQuery?

Comment: Look into the `location` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var a = location.pathname + location.search
```

If for some reason you also want the hash also (the `#` part of the url), use this instead:

```
var a = location.pathname + location.search + location.hash
```

Then, you must remove your app root path from `a`:

```
a = a.replace( "/MyApp/", "" );
// or
a = a.substring( "/MyApp/".length );
```

Answer (score 3):

There isn't much built in for this, as your app and a browser won't actually agree on what the "*root*" is.

To a browser, `/MyApp/` is just another directory name under the root, which it's convinced is:

```
http://localhost:8080/
```

However, if you can get a "*base*" URL from your application:

```
var baseUrl = "http://localhost:8080/MyApp";
```

You can then `.replace()` that from the current `href`:

```
var pagePath = window.location.href.replace(baseUrl, "");

console.log(pagePath);
// "/MyScreen?userName=ccc"
```

Example, using a mock `location` object: http://jsfiddle.net/CWcvW/